# How to run a symfony project in localhost

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, symfony4

I am new to symfony. I have to make some changes in a existing symfony project, that is hosted in aws in a ec2 instance, with no rds instance. I already clone the project code in my local pc, now where I can find a copy of the database so that I can import that in my phpmyadmin and run the project locally.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on Symfony version, Databse type, if Doctrine is used (or something else, like Medoo), but in general, you dont need a copy of DB, rather ran a command (if you use Doctrine), read more here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Also, please exaplain more about your Symfony version//DB//etc..

Comment: Hi, the symfony version is 4.3.5 , and its MYSQL database.